# PowerShell expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I've been tasked with rewriting some scripts to C# rather than PowerShell and batch scripts it is currently in.

Can anyone help me figure out what the following does?

```
Get-Content 'InputName' | %{
    $_ -replace "([^,]+,)\\\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\([^\r$]*)", '$1$2'
} | Set-Content "OutputName"
```

It gets the file from the `InputName` path, does the regular expression and then outputs it to the `OutputName` path, but I can't figure out what the expression does.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow[SO]`, please be a bit more specific when asking question: "*What have you tried so far with code example?*" / "*What do you expect?*" / "*What error do you get?*" **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes the contents of a file 'InputName', runs it through a regular expression and outputs it to the file 'OutputName'.

The expression takes something in front of a comma, plus the comma itself and concatenates it with something that's behind a double backslash, some text, a backslash, some text and another backslash.

So it looks like it can take something like

```
abc,\\server\folder1\test.txt
```

and convert it to

```
abc,test.txt
```

Try to get hold of actual input and output files and confirm.